# Property on a Service is not updating

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I am facing this problem on my login system:
The property on the service menuService is not updating.

Workflow:
On a succeeded post login I am changing the variable menuService.isUserLoggedIn but is not updating correctly as you can see on the console.log. What am I doing wrong/ or missing?

CODE:

```
app.factory('menuService', function(){
    return {
        isUserLoggedIn: false,
    }
})

app.factory('userService', function($http, menuService){
    var doLogin = function(user){
        $http.post('/login', user)
            .success(function(data, status, header, config){
                menuService.isUserLoggedIn = true
            })
            .error(function(data, status, header, config){
                console.log('Error ' + data)
            })
    }
    return {
        doLogin: doLogin
    }
})
app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, userService, menuService){
    $scope.user = {}

    $scope.doLogin = function(user){
        console.log(menuService.isUserLoggedIn) //FALSE
        userService.doLogin(user)
        console.log(menuService.isUserLoggedIn) //FALSE BUT I think should be TRUE
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`$http.post()` is asynchronous so you need return its promise and use the `.then()` method  to check the value when it's done...

```
app.factory('userService', function($http, menuService){
    var doLogin = function(user){
        return $http.post('/login', user)
            .then(function(){
                menuService.isUserLoggedIn = true
            }, function(response){
                console.log('Error ' + response.data)
            });
    };
    return {
        doLogin: doLogin
    }
})
app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, userService, menuService){
    $scope.user = {}

    $scope.doLogin = function(user){
        console.log(menuService.isUserLoggedIn) //FALSE
        menuService.doLogin(user).then(function() {
            console.log(menuService.isUserLoggedIn);
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: but .success will execute only after the post is done, right? So the code that I posted should work...

Comment: That's exactly why the original code didn't work. It calls doLogin, which *starts* the http call, then the console.log is invoked (printing false because the http call is still ongoing). When the http call finishes, that's when the success callback is executed and the value set to true (that happens after the console.log).